# Why is the MongoDB $set not updating document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
db.collection('users', function(err, users)
{
    if (!err)
    {
        users.update({company:cursor[i].name}, {$set:{active:false}}, function() {});
    }
});
```

`cursor[i].name` has a string value and it displays fine when I `console.log()` it.

The document is not being updated. I am using a remote database in MongoHQ and running a Node.js server with the native mongodb driver. If I run the query on the shell while connected to the same database it works fine.

**EDIT:** I used an int instead of `false` and it worked fine. Can I insert booleans into mongodb? If so, how?

Comment: What you're doing should work fine for an int or a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Tested it with 1.2.9 of the driver and it works fine.

```
exports.shouldUpdateCorrectlyWithBoolean = function (test) {
  var db = new Db(MONGODB, new Server("127.0.0.1", 27017,
    {auto_reconnect: false, poolSize: 1}), {w: 1, native_parser: false});

  db.open(function (err, db) {
    db.collection('update_with_boolean').insert({company: 'a'}, function(err, result) {
      test.equal(null, err);

      db.collection('update_with_boolean').update({company: 'a'}, {$set: {active:false}}, function(err, result) {
        test.equal(null, err);
        test.equal(1, result);

        db.collection('update_with_boolean').findOne(function(err, item) {
          test.equal(null, err);
          test.equal(false, item.active);

          db.close();
          test.done();
        });
      });
    })
  });
}
```